# How to open service port?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, iis-7

I'm getting an error code 10061 when calling a WCF service.  The error is

> Could not connect to `<service uri`>.  The connection attempt lasted for a time span of   xxxx.  TCP error code 10061.  No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

When I do a

```
netstat -a
```

I don't see that the port this net.tcp service address should be on is listening.  In IIS, the website this service is under has started.  Any ideas why the port isn't listed in TCP as listening or how I can get it to listen?